# i have been using reverse geocoding api and then i got this error?

Tags: flutter, dart, maps, reverse-geocoding, google-geocoding-api

> E/flutter (23931): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)]
> Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value
> range is empty: 0

```dart
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:rider_app/Assistants/resquestAssitant.dart';
import 'package:rider_app/configMaps.dart';

class AssistantMethods {
  static Future<String> searchCoordinateAddress(Position position) async {
    String placeAddress = "";
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json? latlng=${position.latitude},${position.longitude}&key=$code";
    var response = await RequestAssistant.getRequest(url);

    if (response != "failed") {
      placeAddress = response["results"][0]["formatted_address"]; 
    }

    return placeAddress;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This means that the API didn't return results, you are accessing `response["results"][0]` unconditionally, but it can, and in your case did, actually not return any results.

You should check if it's not empty and that their is indeed a list of results, then access index[0].

This result could happen if you pass coordinates for example, but Google couldn't interpret into a place or human readable address. Happens a lot if you're on an emulator, or assign random starting `LatLng(0.0,0.0)`  which is in the middle of the Atlantic ocean. I've done similar things before. Or basically any other reason to not let Google return a response, if you set a rate limit on your API, or caught in an infinity loop that ends up temporarily rate limiting your API requests. Check those first.

Change your if statement to this:

```
if (response != "failed" && response["results"].isNotEmpty ) {
  placeAddress = response["results"][0]["formatted_address"];
}else{
placeAddress = "Error in retrieving address info";}
```